# Pandas Install library via text file

Tags: pandas, installation

I want to install a python/pandas library which can be found here: http://www.randalolson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/rso_stats.py

I have tried installing it with:

```
pip install rso_stats.py
```

but only got an error message

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement rso-stats.py
```

I think I have to copy the text into a file on my own computer and run some commands but after an hour and a half of googling, I have no clue how to this.

Comment: You are trying to install someone's python script and not a library, if you want to install pandas then just do `pip install pandas`. if that fails then come back.

Comment: Sorry, he called it a "custom python library" so I figured it was somehow different from a script. I guess I can just copy and paste the code I want into pandas and run it that way

Comment: If you have pandas installed then just download the script or code and you can use immediately, no need to install it